# Затемнение tr при ajax запросе, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытаюсь "затемнить" и показать лоадер-иконку для `tr` при изменении значения `select`. Получаю в итоге http://joxi.ru/J2blk11h89B3r6.jpg - то есть вместо `tr` применяется ко всем дочерним `td`. Код привожу (незначимые детали убрал). Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема и как это решить.

HTML:

```
<tr id="123" class="status2">
        <td></td> 
        <td></td> 
        <td></td> 
        <td></td> 
        <td></td> 
        <td></td> 
        <td></td> 
        <td class="agent_td">
            <select name="status" class="form-control status2">
                ' . $options_html_code. '
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

JS:

```
var usersFullAjax = (function() {
var $target,
    $parent_target;

var _ajax = function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php?user=' + $parent_target.attr('id'),
        type: 'GET',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $parent_target.addClass("loading");
        },
        success: function(response) {
            //alert(response)
        },
        complete: function() {
            $parent_target.removeClass("loading");
        },
    });

}
return {
    'init': function() {
        $(document).on('change', 'select[name="status"]', function() {
            $target = $(this);
            $parent_target = $target.parents('tr');
            _ajax($target);
        });
   }
}

})();

usersFullAjax.init();
```

CSS:

```
.loading {
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(82, 94, 100, 200) url('http://sampsonresume.com/labs/pIkfp.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил следующим образом:

```
        beforeSend: function() {
            $parent_target.after('<tr id="tr_load"><td colspan="7" class="loading"></td></tr>');
            $parent_target.hide();
        },

        complete: function() {
            var tr_load = $('#tr_load'); 
            tr_load.remove(); 
            $parent_target.show();
        },
```

Рубрика "сам спросил, сам ответил", да, всё по канону ;)